# How to set the delay before changing slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I use [Slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). I need to set the delay before changing slide, how can I realize this task?

Here is slider's JS-code:

```
  $(".intro__slider").slick({
    infinite: true,
    dots: true,
    dotsClass: "intro__dots",
    arrows: false,
    swipe: false,
    draggable: false
  });

  var introTitle = $(".intro__title"),
      introSlide = $(".intro__slide"); 

  $(".intro__slider").on("beforeChange", function () {
    introTitle.addClass("intro__title_hidden");
    introSlide.addClass("intro__slide_overlayed");
  });

  $(".intro__slider").on("afterChange", function () {
    introTitle.removeClass("intro__title_hidden");
    introSlide.removeClass("intro__slide_overlayed");
  });
```

[Here is full code on codepen](https://codepen.io/SilencerWeb/pen/mwvONj)

Comment: you can use `autoplaySpeed: 3000,` in slick options

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
// On before slide change
$('.your-element').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

    setTimeout(function() {
        //your code to be executed after 1 second
    }, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `autoplaySpeed: 3000`, in slick options

```
$(".intro__slider").slick({
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  infinite: true,
  dots: true,
  dotsClass: "intro__dots",
  arrows: false,
  swipe: false,
  draggable: false
});
```

Comment: You wrote before I click on add answer. Way to go [su]!

Answer (score 0):

you can use speed to 3000

```
$(".intro__slider").slick({
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 6000,
    dots: true,
    dotsClass: "intro__dots",
    arrows: false,
        speed:3000
  });
```

will make the transition in 3 sec, but it won't make a delay, to use a delay I would recommend to use your own dots buttons and the methods slickGoTo  , slickNext